# Unable to run bluemix container No tenant network

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud, etherpad

I am following the etherpad tutorial.

I created a container on **ubuntu** and ran it locally. The push to **bluemix** worked. However when I try to run the container on **bluemix** I get the following error:

> Sorry, an error occurred on our side: Unable to create the network. No
>   tenant network is available for allocation. [Incident ID
>   e1d83d17ff51f0ae]

Is this temporary failure or my fault?

I ran the following command

```
$ sudo ice run -p 9080 --name ethernotes registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net/alicesbox/notes:latest
```

Comment: Are you still having this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is a temporary failure.  The response says "an error occurred on our side".  When an IBM Container is created it is given a private IP address reachable only by other containers sharing the account.  The system was unable to give your instance that address.

Try again.

After your instance has been created you can make it public-facing by giving it a public IP address.